# Suppose that $X_i$ is zero-dimensional for all $i \in I$. Show that the product $X = \prod_{i \in I} X_i$ is zero-dimensional.

Tags: general-topology

> Suppose that $X_i$ is zero-dimensional for all $i \in I$ where $I$ is an arbitary index set. Show that the product $X = \prod_{i \in I} X_i$ is zero-dimensional.

Suppose that $X_i$'s are zero-dimensional. Then for each $i$ we have a basis consisting of closed sets $\mathscr{B}_i$ corresponding to each $X_i$.

The definition of the product topology states that any element $B \in \mathscr{B}$ has the form $$B = \bigcap_{j \in K} \operatorname{pr}_j^{-1} [V_j]$$ where $V_j$ is open in $X_j$. However each $V_j$ is some union of basis elements in $\mathscr{B}_j$ and thus $V_j = \bigcup_{n=1}^k B_{j_n}$. These $B_{j_n}'s$ are closed by our assumption so $V_j$ is actually closed(?). This implies that $B \in \mathscr{B}$ is a finite intersection of closed sets (the projection is continous) making $B$ closed an thus $\mathscr{B}$ is a base of closed sets making $X$ zero-dimensional.

Notes:

1. I think I'm making some sort of mistake by first stating that $V_j$ are open and on the other hand concluding that they are closed. The mistake is probably the fact that $V_j$ can be an arbitary union of these basis sets and arbitary union of closed sets are not neccessarily closed.
2. Instead of the preimage-intersection representation should I consider the alternative that is the product form for $B$?

Answer (score 1):

First of all $X_i$ has a base consisting of *closed-and-open* (clopen) sets, call it $\mathcal{B}_i$. Not a base of closed sets.

Then the set of all $\bigcap_{j \in K} \pi_j^{-1}[B_j]$ where all $B_j \in \mathcal{B}_j$ and $K \subseteq I$ is **finite** is a base for $\prod_{i \in I} X_i$ and all these sets are clopen too (finite intersections of opens are open and all intersections of closed sets are closed). So the product is zero-dimensional QED.

Comment: Instead of considering a basis element of $\mathcal{B}_j$ under the projections what happens if you consider an open set of $X_j$ as the definition states? This should work either way right?

Comment: @Jasper no, you need a clopen set to take the inverse image. Otherwise the base element isn’t clopen. But it’s standard to restrict to basic sets in the component spaces anyway. This always gives a more efficient base than the standard base based on all open sets.

Comment: So it's a _stronger_ arguement when working with basis sets instead of the open sets which all in all are unions of the basis elements? I wonder why is the definition constructed with open sets and not the basis sets?

Comment: @Jasper the text wants to give the full definition of the product topology using the standard subbase and base. Then often there is a theorem that says we can just pick basic open sets (or subbasic open sets) instead of *all* open sets in the components of the standard base and we still get a base for the product topology. That way we can see that a countable product of second countable spaces is second countable and thus also that the product of zero-dimensional spaces is zero-dimensional.